# Do I need a visa to travel to Paris from London if I am a U.S. citizen?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, france, paperwork, us-citizens

I am going on a trip to London, and then I will be going directly to Paris. I am an American citizen; therefore, I do not need a visa to go to London, but I am not sure about Paris.

Answer (score 4):

No, as a US citizen you can stay in the Schengen Area visa-free for up to 90 days within a 180-day period.

Do make sure your passport is valid at least 3 months after leaving Schengen (comprising most of mainland Europe).

Answer (score 2):

If you are visiting for tourist purposes, Americans (and Canadians, and many other nationalities) do not require visas for short stays. The EU will permit you to stay in the Schengen area (which includes France) for up to 90 days visa-free.